# Is there a way to mask mesh in Blender

Tags: modeling, mesh, masking

Regarding the title, is there a way to mask mesh in Blender. Recently I have come across a  guide from a game(Zepeto) that allow player to create their very own asset.  However, the guide is only for MAYA and one part of the guide require the creator to mask the mesh.

The following highlighted part is the purpose and usage of the mask.

[image]

It is done in Maya through using a feature known as "Paint Vertex Tool", the right model in the image below is an example from the guide.

[image]

Hence, is there a feature or workflow in Blender that is similar to the guide?

Comment: the link to he guide for anyone who is interested https://studio.zepeto.me/home/guides/creating-your-first-item-3d-modelers

Comment: you can mask vertex groups with the Mask modifier, is it what you're looking for?

Comment: yea, what @moonboots said, there is a mask modifier that sounds just like what you need.  just select the vertices in edit mode that you want to be masked, add them to a new vertex group, then assign the vertex group to the mask modifier in the mask modifier settings

Comment: thank you for the replied , really appreciated it. Truth to be told, I'm not even sure if the mask modifier is what I'm looking for as I not aware of such method until coming upon the guide. However, I will try the mask modifier and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

The mask modifier can hide unuseful vertices, but it's an internal Blender modifier that will not work in Unity or others softwares. I think it's better to select the unuseful vertices, press P to separate them into another object and include or exclude this new object during FBX export, as needed.

Comment: That unfortunate. However,  I wish to stick to being as close as to the guide, as this is  the criteria for require to be accepted for the game. Still,  Thank you for the replied, really  appreciated it.

Comment: What happens under the hood is that the vertices which have been painted in black are treated as deleted, so they are not transferred into the Unity Prefab. The only way to stay more stick to the guide is to buy a Maya license!